# Element properties for nwd files in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

When I query element properties in Autodesk forge for a model that is based on NWD file, I only get small set of the element properties than what I see in NavisWorks Manage. On the other hand, when I query the properties for models based on Revit rvt files, I can see all the properties. Is there anyway to get the full properties for nwd files?
Just to clarify, I am asking about properties that are already in the NWD file and I can see it in Navisworks.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set viewer selection mode by

`viewer.setSelectionMode(Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionMode.FIRST_OBJECT)`

and then you can get the properties you want.

There are 3 different type: `FIRST_OBJECT`, `LAST_OBJECT`, `LEAF_OBJECT`. the default is `LEAF_OBJECT` .

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tried it in the console, and it still only shows the material properties only. Would you elaborate more?

Comment: In the console, you can use `viewer.getProperties(dbId, console.log)` to check the properties of the dbId you want select. e.g. you can select `dbId === 12` like `viewer.getProperties(12, console.log)`, if the 12 has one property whose `displayName` is `parent` and `displayValue` is `11`, you can try `viewer.getProperties(11, console.log)`. `setSelectionMode` is used to set mouse left click mode, if you set `LEAF_OBJECT`, when you click a construct, you may select `12`; if you set `FIRST_OBJECT`, you may select `11`

Answer (score 0):

The [Model Derivative API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2) will only extract information available on the original file, there are no settings on this process (e.g. which properties to extract), except selecting 2D or 3D views.

If you need information as presented in Revit, then consider using the .RVT file.